# Running the batch file in background continuesly

Tags: batch-file

I have one batch file which runs one java application. After running the batch it opens the java command line. I have to run it in the background continuously then an then only my application will work properly.
So, How to do that?

Comment: you want to start the batch file as a background process or to change the state of already running script?

Comment: Run the batch file in background

Answer (score 0):

Here are few options

1) With [hidder.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/iexpress/hidder.bat) - it uses IExpress to wrap the file in an exe which will start as hidden process:

```
call hidder.bat myBat.bat  myexe.exe
call myexe.exe
```

2) With [startHidden.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/ProcessesUtils/startHidden.bat) - It will require admin permissions (a.k.a "run As Administrator") as it uses SCHTASKS to create a scheduled task that will start the bat. It will also return the PID of the process.

```
call startHidden.bat myBat.bat
```

3) [ShellRunJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/ShellRunJS.bat) - it uses [WScript.Shell.Run()](https://ss64.com/vb/run.html) method .

```
call ShellRunJS.bat "my.bat" -style 0 -wait yes
```

4) With [win32process.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/wsh/win32process.bat) - it uses [Win32_ProcessStartup wmi class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-processstartup) and returns the PID of the process. Requires full path to the bat file:

```
call win32process.bat "%cd%\my.bat"  -showWindow 0
```

5) With [ProcessStartJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/ProcessStartJS.bat) - it is a selfcompiled .net application and creates a small exe file. Also returns the PID of the started bat and also requires a full path:

```
call processStartJs.bat "%cd%\b1.bat" -style Hidden -directory "."
```

6) As an alternative you can also change the state of already running bat file by taking its PID with [getCmdPid.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat) and [windowMode.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat):

```
call getCmdPid.bat
call windowMode -pid %errorlevel% -mode hidden
```

Comment: These solutions also not helping me

Comment: @AnmolBudhewar - what issues you have with them? Give more context.

Comment: my batch file is not running in the background by using these solution

Comment: @AnmolBudhewar - with none of them?Does you bat start another bat with `START` command? or another console application? Can you try these solutions with more simple script E.g. `@timeout 5 > test.file` to see if it will start something more simple in background modde?

Comment: while running the second solution it only shows the PID but not runs the batch file

Comment: I want to run batch continuously.

Comment: @AnmolBudhewar - this probably means that that the batch is running ,but as you requested in a background mode - without visible window. You can add `echo something>to.some.file` on few key places in order to check how it is running.

Comment: can you provide any example or how can I do it